# SQL where clause order can change performance in postgresql10

Tags: sql, postgresql

In general, can where clause order change performance in postgresql? Can you provide an example where it's can happen?

Answer (score 0):

No it doesn't change performance for two reasons:

1. a dbms doesn't execute the query as you write, with an sql statement you are asking for something, but there is a module called optimizer that create an internal representation of the query so if you have two queries that produce the same result a good optimizer convert these two queries in the same representation.
2. where clauses are performed after reading the target table, so let's say that you have a table called t and two where clauses like these: where a > b and c < d. What the dbms does is reading the table (heavy operation) and while reading it looks for where clauses and select only records that match both clauses.

Comment: Do you have proofs?

Comment: you can read this http://dbdmg.polito.it/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/4-QueryOptimization-x61.pdf and you can show execution plan with explain

Comment: It just slides is not the good proof. Who are these people(Elena Baralis, Silvia Chiusano,Politecnico di Torino) Is it one of the Postgres developers or something like that?

Comment: once again you can see execution plan, it doesn't matter if it is postgres once dbms read the table and load in memory it check for where clauses. SQL is an imperative language so you say what to do not how to do, Java for example is a declarative language so if you say: if (a && b) you are cheching for a first and then b. Politecnico is a university and Baralis is a data scientis since 30 years

Comment: Do you understand that order a and b in If operator( if( a && b) ) change performance in java?

Comment: yes and this is what I'm tryn to tell you in java operations will be executed in the write order and this change the performance, in sql you say select something where a and b but a dbms won't execute a before b, so there's not difference between write where a and b or write b and a, a dbms takes the decision by itself